# Laravel: Deploy and vendor folder

Tags: deployment, laravel

I've just finished a simple work done in Laravel 4 and I'm ready to Deploy on my server.

I found that the vendor folder has a size of 100MB and I wonder if it is necessary to upload all its subfolders. 
I suppose that I don't use the most of those libraries, is there a good practise to follow to deploy a Laravel project?

Answer (score 11):

You better use

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel --prefer-dist <project directory>
```

To create your project. Your vendor dir space usage will start at 10MB, only. (I just did it it here and that's what downloaded for me).

And looks like you also can:

```
composer update --no-dev --prefer-dist
```

To reduce your current project space usage.

But... vendor directory and all its first level subdirectories are mandatory (as long as you are using all the packages you have installed), but there are some subdirectories inside them you may easily ignore when deploying, such as:

```
*/examples/*
*/docs/*
*/docs2/* (Doctrine)
*/tests/*
*/test/*
*/Tests/* (Carbon)
*/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/notes/*
```

Answer (score 5):

I haven't deployed an L4 app myself to this point, but will run into issues as I don't have git/composer access on my host server as well. Unless something clever comes along, FTP/SSH is my only avenue for getting my files on the server.

The `/vendors` folder is **absolutely required** in order for your application to function.  Think of vendors as the `/core` folder in other frameworks. All of the heavy lifting in Laravel is managed through the packages contained inside of `/vendors`, and so without that folder your app will just crash.

Answer (score 3):

You should not upload the vendor folder, insted you should run composer install/update on your server where you deploy. You should only deploy your application files.

Comment: I haven't an ssh access on this server. I have only an FTP access

Comment: And if it's a shared host (like many people have) without SSH?

Comment: @Frug: that sounds terrible :) I guess you're out of luck and have to deploy your vendor folder. In my opinion, the downsides of shared hosting are enormous. You're missing out on the power of composer, git and artisan (if it's an L4 app).

Comment: @KarlLaurentiusRoos Why do so many devs make silly assumptions about the requirements of other devs? This comes up again and again, and all it does is cause noise. I have a private server, the original question talks about deployment. Sometimes deployment means deploying to shared hosts. It's part of project requirements and it's how the world works sometimes.